# How does block transfer take place between the different levels of cache

Tags: computer-science, cpu-architecture, cpu-cache

I was trying to understand the block transfer between the two levels of cache (suppose L1 and L2), let L1 has a block size of 4 words and L2 has a block size of 16 words, the data bus between L1 and L2 is of 4 words. If a miss occurs in L1 cache, how will the data transfer take place, **are all the words transferred simultaneously in parellel (between L1 and L2 cache) with only one memory access** (since the data bus size is equal to the size of the L1 cache) or it takes 4 memory accesses to transfer 4 words between L1 and L2 cache. Please help.

Comment: Caches often only track present / absent at the level of a whole cache line.  So if L1d needs data in a cache line, it will fetch the whole thing from an outer level of cache.  If the bus is wide enough to do the whole thing in one cycle, then yes of course it will transfer it in a single wide transfer.  Related: [How can cache be that fast?](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/329955) shows the bus widths and bandwidth in a modern Intel CPU.

Comment: okay that means it would take only one memory access from L2 cache to transfer 4 words across a 4 bit wide data bus, right?

Comment: 4 bit wide?  You said the bus was 4 *words* wide, equal to the cache line size.  Anyway, unless stated otherwise, you should assume that data is transferred at one bus-width per cycle until a whole cache line has been sent.  It might be sent critical-word first to enable faster early restart (https://www.cs.umd.edu/~meesh/cmsc411/website/projects/ramguide/cache/cache.html#ercwf), but the whole line will be sent.  There might also be more than 1 cycle of latency for the L2 to retrieve the line.

Comment: yeah that's 4 words wide sorry for that error, that would mean if instead the block size of L1 was say 16 words then it would take nearly four cycles to fetch one complete cache line from L2 or transfer one complete cache line from L2 to L1. Great Thanks